# Display WordPress posts on external webpage

Tags: php, wordpress

I am running WordPress functions on an external webpage to get posts and pages. The functions work fine.

I am using

```
the_content();
```

to display the body of the posts but it doesn't seem to be keeping the correct formatting. The HTML is displaying fine, but the line breaks etc are not.

Here is the full PHP code i am using:

```
$page = get_page_by_id($_GET["p"], OBJECT, 'post');
    query_posts('p='.$page->ID.'');
    if($page->ID) {
        while (have_posts()) {
            the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><br>
            Posted on <?php the_date(); ?><br><br>
            <?php
            the_content();
        }
    }
```

Screenshot of my site: *http://postimg.org/image/nc2xw6af3/*

Screenshot of the Wordpress Template: *http://postimg.org/image/r01znya1p/*

Comment: Please provide more details and possibly a screen shot of the issue.

Comment: You're not providing enough information, but I suspect [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) may be useful.

Comment: Maybe it's css problem? Show us the output HTML.

Comment: here is the output HTML on my website - http://pastebin.com/5Yuve1gg

Comment: here is the output HTML on the Wordpress template - http://pastebin.com/dAuWFvsE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the required CSS information is missing.  You need to include the CSS for `<h2>` and `<p>` tags from the WordPress template.